# Exporting a plot without drawing it

Tags: export

I'm trying to create a rather big 3D image and export it. Currently, I create the image then display using `Show`, then use `Export`. The problem is that drawing the 3D image as an interactive object is absolutely caning my little laptop, and I don't really need it - I just want a *jpeg* output. Any way to do this?

What I am doing is basically along the lines of

```
Show[{object list}, options]
Export["name.jpeg",%,options]
```

So as an example, if I wanted an image of a `Sin[x]` graph without *Mathematica* first "drawing" it, how would I do it?

Thanks

Comment: I think the following will do the job: `plot=Show[...]; Export["name.png",plot]`

Comment: That did the job, thank you.

Comment: Maybe [reading about semicolon](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18617#18617) will help.

Answer (score 4):

If you really want to export the graphics only, then the most direct way is probably

```
Export["name.jpeg", Show[{object list}, options], exportoptions]
```

which returns only the file name of the exported graphics. Another common thing is, as Kuba suggested, to suppress the output with `;`

```
plot = Show[{object list}, options];
Export["name.jpeg", plot,options]
```